# Build TDS project in Azure Devop Pipeline

Tags: tds

I'm having some trouble trying to build my Sitecore 9.2 solution in an Azure Devops build pipeline.  The project/solution builds great locally and I'm able to generate my CM and CD WDPs.  But while building in the pipeline, I'm seeing the following error:

`Error MSB4057: The target "Build" does not exist in the project.`

Anyone seen that?  I'm using the nuget package for 6.0.0.10.  I tried copying up the TDS targets file to my repo so that I could reference it directly in my TDS csproj files like:

`<Import Project="..\..\..\..\tools\HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.targets" Condition="Exists('..\..\..\..\tools\HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.targets')" />`

but that didn't seem to help.

I haven't seen anyone talking about this in regards to TDS projects, so I assume I have missed some obvious configuration step, but does anyone have any ideas to check?

Thanks!

Comment: I was able to resolve this.  As Nikhil suggested and as I had documented in my question, you need to have a reference to the targets file that is local to both your local build and build server.  I additionally edited the targets file itself to comment-out the "VerifyTDSVersion" task as that was the next problem I encountered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will suggest go to your `.scproj file` in a text editor, and make sure that you have right references which is reference to the `HedgeHogDevelopment Nuget` Package Folder.

Anything that references to your `c:\program files (x86)\Hedgehog Development\`

Should be removed

This is what it looks like

```
  <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\HedgehogDevelopment.TDS.6.0.0.10\build\HedgehogDevelopment.TDS.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\HedgehogDevelopment.TDS.6.0.0.10\build\HedgehogDevelopment.TDS.targets'))" />
  </Target>
  <Import Project="..\packages\HedgehogDevelopment.TDS.6.0.0.10\build\HedgehogDevelopment.TDS.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\HedgehogDevelopment.TDS.6.0.0.10\build\HedgehogDevelopment.TDS.targets')" />
```